# EasyPHP unable to access PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, easyphp

sorry I'm aware of a few of these issues already on here, however mine is a fresh install of EasyPHP, I have not changed any of the settings yet I'm still unable to access PHPMyAdmin. I get the following error:

Error
MySQL said:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I've checked the initial settings and as far as I can tell it should be right. I also installed a second one in the C:\ drive and still no luck.

Comment: What does your config.inc.php look like?

Comment: @ajreal Ok, not to be an ass, but please justify why you feel the need to edit my question, downgrade me, and add and irrelevant comment.

Comment: **edit:-** change the format, **downgrade:-**, programming 101, when there is an error, check the error message **comment:-** everyone can speak

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

If you get the following error, it means that you are using an incorrect root password:

```
shell> mysqladmin -u root -pxxxx ver
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If the preceding error occurs even when you have not specified a password, it means that you have an incorrect password listed in some option file. Try the --no-defaults option as described in the previous item.

For information on changing passwords, see Section 5.5.5, “Assigning Account Passwords”.

If you have lost or forgotten the root password, see Section C.5.4.1, “How to Reset the Root Password”.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html